# React Native Navigate to screen outside render

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Route')}>
            ...
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

};


export default class HorizontalList extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
          return (
                <FlatList
                    ...
                    renderItem={({item: rowData}) => {
                        return (
                            <Card
                                thumb_image={rowData.thumb_image}
                                title={rowData.title}
                                innerSubTitle={rowData.innerSubTitle}
                                innerMainTitle={rowData.innerMainTitle}
                            />
                        );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                />
            );
    }
}
```

I want to add a onPress in Card that will open another screen in the app. Constant is declared outside the render and Card is called as a template inside the render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass navigation to Card

```
<Card
   navigation={this.props.navigation}
   thumb_image={rowData.thumb_image}
   title={rowData.title}
   innerSubTitle={rowData.innerSubTitle}
   innerMainTitle={rowData.innerMainTitle}
/>
```

and use like this:

```
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Route')}>
            ...
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

};
```

Comment: When is do that i get and error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: Try console log `this.ptops.navigation` inside `HorizontalList ` and tell me what you get...

Comment: Sorry. i did not pass navigation to HorizontalList Component. Its working now.